# Invalid data after declaration Kivy Tutorial #5 - Object Properties and .kv Continued

Tags: kivy

I am brand new to coding and am working my way thru the tech with tim kivy youtube turtorials. I am following his code for the most part but am trying to tailor it to the app I'm trying to develop. I am getting the following error message and have no idea how to fix it.

```
line 3:
 ...
       1:<MyGrid>
       2:
 >>    3:    FirstName: FirstName
       4:    LastName: LastName
       5:    Email: Email
 ...
 Invalid data after declaration

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is the code I'm entering. I have no idea how to even look for the problem.
Any advise on debugging or learning is greatly appreciated!

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.bubble import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class MyGrid(Widget):
    FirstName = ObjectProperty(None)
    LastName = ObjectProperty(None)
    Email = ObjectProperty(None)
    Address = ObjectProperty(None)
    Bankname = ObjectProperty(None)
    AccountNumber = ObjectProperty(None)
    RoutingNumber = ObjectProperty(None)




class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()


if  __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your property names begin with a lowercase letter, and make sure your widget classes begin with an uppercase letter. Kv language uses this to distinguish between them, and by not following that rule you have it looking for a widget named FirstName.

Comment: thank you so much! I had no idea capitalization was an issue, thanks!!!